# How to use jQuery mobile vclick in IE 10

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer, jquery-mobile

I'm trying to use vclick event to make my page working on mobile devices but this code:

```
$('<div>').on("vclick", function () {
    alert('working');
});
```

is not working in IE 10 when using mouse. It works in Chromium and Firefox and on Android browsers with touch. How can I make it work in IE or is there replacement for vclick that works on IE?

Comment: `$('div')` remove `<>`

Comment: I'm creating this div, it will be appended to existing HTML.

Comment: For dynamic items, `$(document).on('vclick', 'div', function ()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suspect this is related to the fact that you didn't provide any size (or content) to the div. This, combined to the way IE handles event bubbling (see IE event model) is probably the cause.

Try to investigate the problem by adding some content to the div.

You could also try to attach your event handler only once the 'div' node has been attached (use appendTo) the DOM tree.

Comment: I don't remember what I did to make it work but it was something like adding background to the div. So it is working now but I don't remember why.